# Poisson process, exponential arrivals problem

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, poisson-process, exponential-distribution

I cannot for the life of me see why my solution method gives me the wrong result.

> A machine works for an exponentially distributed time with rate $\mu$ then fails. A crew checks the machine at times according to a Poisson process with rate $\lambda$; if the machine has failed, it's immediately replaced. Find the expected time between replacements.

*Ross* Probability Models, 10th Ed. Ch. 5, Ex. 37.

**My Solution:** Let $T_M$ be time until machine's failure. Let $T_C$ be time until the crew checks. Let $T_R$ be time until the next replacement.

$$\begin{split}E[T_R]&=E[T_R|T_M\leq T_C]P(T_M\leq T_C)+E[T_R|T_C\leq T_M]P(T_C\leq T_M)\\
 &=\left(\frac1\mu+\frac1\lambda\right)\left(\frac\mu{\lambda+\mu}\right)+\left(\frac1\lambda+E[T_R]\right)\left(\frac\lambda{\lambda+\mu}\right).\\
 &\Rightarrow E[T_R]=\frac2\mu+\frac1\lambda\end{split}$$

but the solutions manual disagrees and suggests

$$\frac1\mu+\frac1\lambda$$

where did I make an error?

Comment: First you wait until the machine fails (exp(\mu)), then you wait for arrival of a crew member (exp(\lambda)), hence $E(T_R)=\frac 1 \mu+\frac 1 \lambda$. Why are you comparing $T_C$ with $T_M$? Arrivals of a crew matter only after $T_M$.

Comment: I'm thinking that if the crew arrives before a failure, nothing happens and the process restarts, albeit with the extra time from the crew's first arrival.

Comment: What *exactly* is $T_C$?

Comment: @A.S. The exponentially distributed time-until-arrival for crew.

Comment: Which time exactly - from what moment that is?

Comment: You're right, I should use a subindex $T_{C_i}$ for the $i$th crew arrival. But they're all i.i.d.

Comment: Which $T_{C_i}$ are you comparing with $T_M$? Why are you comparing $T_C$ with $T_M$ at all?

Comment: Well, I partitioned the event $T_R$ into two possibilities; machine failure first, or crew arrival first. If machine fails first, that is the event $T_M\leq T_C$. If crew arrives first, that is the event $T_C\leq T_M$. In the former case, $T_R$ is just the time of machine failure plus the time 'till crew arrival. In the latter case, I waited until the crew arrived to do nothing, then I repeat the process (a la memorylessness).

Comment: Then $E(T_R|T_{C_1}\le T_M)=\frac 1 \lambda + \frac 1 \mu$. You are doing pointless separation of $T_R$ in two possibilities.

Comment: I don't understand why I needn't consider the possibility that the first crew arrives for nothing. And why doesn't it give me the same result anyways?

Comment: Because $E(T_R|T_{C_1}\le T_M)=\frac 1 \lambda + \frac 1 \mu\ne\text{what you wrote}$. The end result is the same. There is no point in considering the possibility that the first crew arrives for nothing as there might be 100 crews that arrive for nothing. You first need to wait until the machine breaks down and then wait until the crew comes. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: It seems like I'm misreading the English somewhere but I'm satisfied that I just missed a tacit conditioning in the problem statement. I assumed I was counting the time after a new machine.

Comment: What conditioning? Right after replacement you first wait until another failure and then after failure you wait until the crew comes (that is another replacement).

Comment: Oh, I understand. We don't care about any of the crew arrivals before the first failure, the problem is independent of their arrivals. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a rigorous proof, let $\{N_t\}$ be the Poisson process related to crew check. Accordingly, denote $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ to be the independent random exponential random variables representing the time between events and $S_n = X_1 + \cdots + X_n$.

For fixed $t > 0$, define $X^{(t)} = S_{N_t + 1} - t$. For a machine that starts working at time $0$, if a failure occurs at time $t$, then the time to the replacement is given by $X^{(t)}$. Our goal is to compute $E[X^{(t)}]$.

We first show that conditioning on the event $[N_t = n]$, $X^{(t)} \sim \exp(\lambda)$, which can be proved as follows: for any $y > 0$ and each $n \in \{0, 1, 2, \ldots\}$,
\begin{align}
& P[X^{(t)} > y \mid N_t = n] \\
= & \frac{P[X^{(t)} > y, N_t = n]}{P[N_t = n]} \\
= & \frac{P[S_{N_t + 1} > y + t, N_t = n]}{P[N_t = n]} \\
= & \frac{P[S_{n + 1} > y + t, N_t = n]}{P[N_t = n]} \\
= & \frac{P[S_{n + 1} > y + t, S_n \leq t < S_{n + 1}]}{P[N_t = n]} \tag{$*$} \\
\end{align}
where we used the definition of Poisson process: $[N_t = n] = [S_n \leq t < S_{n + 1}]$. Use independence of $X_{n + 1}$ and $S_n$, if denoting the distribution function of $S_n$ by $G_n$, then the numerator of $(*)$ is:
\begin{align}
& P[S_{n + 1} > y + t, S_n \leq t < S_{n + 1}] \\
= & P[X_{n + 1} > y + t - S_n, S_n \leq t < X_{n + 1} + S_n] \\
= & P[X_{n + 1} > y + t - S_n, S_n \leq t] \\
= & \int_0^t P[X_{n + 1} > y + t - s] dG_n(s) \\
= & \int_0^t e^{-\lambda(y + t - s)} dG_n(s) \\
= & e^{-\lambda y} \int_0^t e^{-\lambda(t - s)} dG_n(s) \\
= & e^{-\lambda y} P[X_{n + 1} > t - S_n, S_n \leq t] \\
= & e^{-\lambda y} P[S_n \leq t < S_{n + 1}] \\
= & e^{-\lambda y} P[N_t = n]. \\
\end{align}
Therefore $(*)$ reads as 
$$P[X^{(t)} > y \mid N_t = n] = e^{-\lambda y}$$
hence the claim is true, consequently, $E[X^{(t)}|N_t = n] = \frac{1}{\lambda}$, then
$$E[X^{(t)}] = E\{E[X^{(t)}|N_t]\} = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty E[X^{(t)}|N_t = n]P[N_t = n] = \frac{1}{\lambda}\sum_{n = 0}^\infty P[N_t = n] = \frac{1}{\lambda}.$$

Finally, suppose a new machine started working at time $0$ (which is also the time the most recent replacement occurs), it failed at $t$, with the notation above, the time it will be replaced is $t + X^{(t)}$. Let $Y$ be the failure time of that machine, the time between replacements $R$ can then be expressed as $R = Y + X^{(Y)}$. Since $Y$ and $N_t$ are independent, we have
$$E[X^{(Y)}] = E\{E[X^{(Y)}|Y]\} = \int_0^\infty E[X^{(t)}|Y = t]\mu e^{-\mu t} dt = \int_0^\infty E[X^{(t)}]\mu e^{-\mu t} dt = \frac{1}{\lambda}.$$
Therefore,
$$E[R] = E[Y] + E[X^{(Y)}] = \frac{1}{\mu} + \frac{1}{\lambda}.$$